# How to query more than two tables in Django?

Tags: django

I want to make a big query with multiple tables. My model will be written below, in which there are 5 `ForeignKeys`, that is, I will touch on 5 tables.

```
  class Transaction(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=False, primary_key=True)
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    deal = models.ForeignKey(Deal, null=True, related_name='deal', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service_instance = models.ForeignKey(ServiceInstance, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payment_source = models.ForeignKey(PayerPaymentSource, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payment_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    context = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Also, `PayerPaymentSource` contains `ForeignKey`.And need will from it another request like `select_related()`

How to implement such a query?

Comment: Would you explain your models more precisely? Nothing is clear flrom your qustion what you are going to do with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Django documentation:

> **select_related()**
>
> Returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships,
>   selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query.
>   This is a performance booster which results in a single more complex
>   query but means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require
>   database queries.
>
> The following examples illustrate the difference between plain lookups
>   and select_related() lookups. Here’s standard lookup:
>
> ```
> # Hits the database.
> e = Entry.objects.get(id=5)
>
> # Hits the database again to get the related Blog object.
> b = e.blog
> ```
>
> And here’s select_related lookup:
>
> ```
> # Hits the database.
> e = Entry.objects.select_related('blog').get(id=5)
>
> # Doesn't hit the database, because e.blog has been prepopulated
> # in the previous query.
> b = e.blog
> ```

And actually answering the question:

In order to select all foreign key relations at once, you need to specify those fields in a `select_related`. If you want to follow foreign key relation two or more levels deep, you need to specify it using `__` notation, like so: `foreignKey_fied__itsForeignKey`.

So you would need to use something like this:

```
Transaction.objects.select_related('currency', 'deal', 'service_instance', 'payment_source__itsForeignKeyField')
```